# Find $a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}+e^{2}$ from certain equalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the equalities $$2(a+b)-6c-3(d+e)=6$$

$$3(a+b)-2c+6(d+e)=2$$

$$6(a+b)+3c-2(d+e)=-3$$

hold simultaneously, evaluate  $a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}+e^{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can easily compute that $a+b = 0$, $c = -1$, $d+e = 0$, so you can get that $a^2-b^2 + c^2 -d^2+e^2 = 1$.